# postgres delete then pg_dump dumping deleted data

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Using postgres 9.5.5

I'm running a script that does a

```
DELETE FROM hugetable
```

where the table 'hugetable' is large and has many millions of rows. I then do a pg_dump on the database and the dump still contains all the data in the table 'hugetable' that I thought was just deleted. I've tried using TRUNCATE on the table but we keep getting locking issues. What are some of the solutions to this? Running VACUUM on the table after I run the DELETE?

Answer (score 1):

Either you rolled the deleting transaction back, or you never committed it and it is still open.

Comment: It's actually not in a transaction. Is that the problem?

Comment: *Everything* is inside a transaction. Do you see your changes if you disconnect and reconnect? Then they are committed, and `pg_dump` will see them. If not, maybe you are dumping a different database than you think you are.